# Help on Netbook Launcher

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, unity

Can i install the netbook launcher together with existing desktop mode and unity mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the release of 10.10 then the `netbook-launcher` package is no longer available in the Ubuntu repositories.

This is because this old **Ubuntu Netbook remix** was superseded by **Unity** and the **Ubuntu Netbook Edition**. Because of this the Netbook Launcher is no longer maintained.

You may wish to see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netbook-remix-launcher/+bug/662082) confirming what I have just said.

Comment: The EFL-based netbook launcher that doesn't use 3D is still available though.

Comment: whats the different between 3D and 2D?

Comment: @Wilsonzaizai basically one offer 3d effects and the other dont. Respectively 3d is compiz, and 2d is metacity.